# Print with jquery and Android

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, printing

I need to print receipts from a mobile miniprinter from an Android device using blue tooth. Is it possible? I would like to do It from a Web browser because I develop in html 5, is that possible too? Or I need to use Java? I'm working with a Zebra miniprinter

Thanks a lot for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Your interface can be HTML, but the app will have to be built with AndroidSDK (Java), and to include printing, you'll have to use Java. But it will only work on Android 4.4 (KitKat) devices.

Here's the abstract class you'll need to implement:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintDocumentAdapter.html

The accepted answer of this question demonstrates what you'll need to do:
[How do I print a WebView using KitKat 4.4 print API via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005430/how-do-i-print-a-webview-using-kitkat-4-4-print-api-via-reflection)