# Open URL intent in landscape mode

Tags: android, url

is possible to open URL site "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets.....ecc" directly in landascape mode?
this is the code that i use to open URL with chrome or google application.

```
mgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets.....ecc"));
            startActivity(viewIntent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can't handle anything outside of your application, unless it is rooted. You can do this by using WebView.

Comment: Like @Tushar said you can add a Webview in your Activity and force its orientation to Landscape.

Comment: thank you guys! i built a webview and work well, now is possible to reproduce a "print button" that we find in the standard menu browser ?

Comment: You can look for it over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005430/how-do-i-print-a-webview-using-kitkat-4-4-print-api-via-reflection?rq=1)